# Not able to access class level private variables from different methods/functions of the same class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, variables, private

In the following I am trying to define a Private variable on Class level called _p. The HTTP.POST for Index will bring a User provided value which I'll set this private variable with. In the second Method called ListOfVehicles, I'll be accessing this variable.

Now everything is alright theoretically, however when I try to access this private variable I don't get anything, this is found Nothing.

```
Public Class QuotationController
  Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

  'Private Variables
  Dim _p As String

  'Get Basic pickup and dropoff details
  Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
  End Function

  'Function to get basic details out of the view
  'and to redirect to ListOfVehicles
  <HttpPost()>
  Function Index(ByVal P As String, ByVal D As String) As ActionResult
    _p = P
    Return RedirectToAction("ListOfVehicles")
  End Function

  'Show list of vehicels
  Function ListofVehicles() As ActionResult
    ViewData("UserChoice") = "Pickup: " & _p 
    vehicleList = QB.GetQuotation(_p, _d)
    Return View(vehicleList)
  End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

That is fundamentally impossible.

Each HTTP request gets a separate controller instance; they don't share anything.

You should use cookies, session, application state, or cache, as appropriate.

In your case, you should probably include that variable in a POST to the other action from a `<form>`.

Comment: It is new to me that each request gets a new instance of the controller. But what about the following:
View # 1 sends some data back to the controller, on the basis of that data View # 2 is displayed to the user. 
View # 2 sends back the data and finally 
View # 3 consolidates everything obtained from View # 1 , 2 and 3 and displayed to the user. 
How is it being done?
Am I making any sense here?

Comment: @user1001493: You need to pass all of the data along with each postback, or use session.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a formal post parameter you can use

```
TempData.Add("P", P);
```

just before the return statement, in your ListOfVeicles you can accesso via

```
string p = TempData["P"];
```

Temp data is valid just within the request scope

EDIT: sorry for C# syntax, I'm not using VB since the good old days ov VB 6

Comment: Thanks for your reply
This does work and solves my problem out.
Is there any particular issue regarding its usage? Like performance, security etc? Is there any other way of achieving the same objectives (any industry specific, best practice)?

Comment: Nope, TempData was added for this very reason, I just add to use at least constants for TempData names (I hate magic string in code). TempData is short lived, therefore it adds no security issues.